# Is there a good extension for working with SVN in Emacs?

Tags: svn, emacs

I've tried [psvn.el](http://www.xsteve.at/prg/vc_svn/), but the command to diff the file you're currently looking at is just hideous: `M-x svn-file-show-svn-diff`. I tried installing [vc-svn.el](http://cvs.savannah.gnu.org/viewvc/emacs/emacs/lisp/vc-svn.el), but couldn't get that working on my version of Emacs: GNU Emacs 21.3.1 (i386-mingw-nt5.1.2600) of 2004-03-10 on NYAUMO. I've tried putting a copy of vc-snv.el in my site-lisp dir, but when I try to run the command "M-x vc-diff" it says my file "is not under version control".

The [emacs wiki page](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SubVersion), which mainly focuses on vc-svn.el, seems to be horribly out of date, as many of the links do not work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can take a look at [dsvn](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/contrib/client-side/emacs/dsvn.el) - it was influenced originally by psvn. However, it can work more efficiently with large repositories containing many files and subdirectories. As a side note - you should really consider upgrading to Emacs 23 - it has loads of cool new features and most newer modes are not tested against older versions of Emacs such as 21, so you could run into unexpected problems.

Comment: Thanks! I'll need some time to get used to this, but so far it seems really nice. At least it works and doesn't require you to type an entire novel to issue a command :P

Comment: What's the difference between psvn and dsvn? People write that "efficiently with large repositories containing many files and subdirectories", but what does that mean, more concretely?

Answer (score 6):

Your emacs is six years old!  Consider upgrading.

Answer (score 2):

Out of the box Emacs supports a [number of different version control systems](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Version-Control-Systems.html#Version-Control-Systems), including SVN. If you use [VC Directory Mode](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/VC-Directory-Mode.html#VC-Directory-Mode) you get the ability to pick and choose what files go into each commit (but you don't get the per-hunk selection that you get with Magit and git). There is additional information there on how to integrate with Change Logs and re-use a ChangeLog entry as the VC commit message (or vice versa).

Answer (score 1):

In recent versions of Emacs SVN support is integrated. My Emacs 23 e.g. supports SVN out of the box.

Comment: But that is still the same psvn.el, but arguably a newer version.